# How to add multiple variable products to the cart via the add-to-cart query string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to add two variable product into my cart when i clicking a link on my site. i added below code in my function.php this code is only working with the simple product its not working with the variable product.

```
function woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart( $url = false ) {
    // Make sure WC is installed, and add-to-cart qauery arg exists, and contains at least one comma.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    $product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $count       = count( $product_ids );
    $number      = 0;

    foreach ( $product_ids as $id_and_quantity ) {
        // Check for quantities defined in curie notation (<product_id>:<product_quantity>)
        // https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/#comment-12236
        $id_and_quantity = explode( ':', $id_and_quantity );
        $product_id = $id_and_quantity[0];

        $_REQUEST['quantity'] = ! empty( $id_and_quantity[1] ) ? absint( $id_and_quantity[1] ) : 1;

        if ( ++$number === $count ) {
            // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action( $url );
        }

        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
        $was_added_to_cart = false;
        $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
            continue;
        }

        $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->get_type(), $adding_to_cart );

        // Variable product handling
        if ( 'variable' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_variable', $product_id );

        // Grouped Products
        } elseif ( 'grouped' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_grouped', $product_id );

        // Custom Handler
        } elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler ) ){
            do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler, $url );

        // Simple Products
        } else {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_simple', $product_id );
        }
    }
}

// Fire before the WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action callback.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );


/**
 * Invoke class private method
 *
 * @since   0.1.0
 *
 * @param   string $class_name
 * @param   string $methodName
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
function woo_hack_invoke_private_method( $class_name, $methodName ) {
    if ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3', '<' ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'PHP version does not support ReflectionClass::setAccessible()', __LINE__ );
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    unset( $args[0], $args[1] );
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( $methodName );
    $method->setAccessible( true );

    $args = array_merge( array( $class_name ), $args );
    return call_user_func_array( array( $method, 'invoke' ), $args );
}
```

Also i want to run this code only one time. If the two product already added in cart then not added the product again into the cart.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function to add multiple variable products to WooCommerce cart.

```
function woocommerce_add_multiple_products_to_cart() {

    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart-manual'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $woocommerce;

    //'add-to-cart' should be in this format - product_id1|variation_id1|variation_attribute1|variation_value1,product_id2|variation_id2|variation_attribute2|variation_value2 ...
    $product_var_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart-manual'] ); //product with variation ids that needs to be added

    foreach ( $product_var_ids as $product_var_id ) {
        $pdt_var_temp = explode( '|', $product_var_id );
        $product_id = $pdt_var_temp[0];
        $variation_id = $pdt_var_temp[1];
        $variation_attribute = $pdt_var_temp[2];
        $variation_attribute_value = $pdt_var_temp[3];

        $pdt_in_cart = false;

        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {      
            if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $variation_id ) ) {  
                $pdt_in_cart = true;                
            }
        }

         if ( !$pdt_in_cart ) {   
            $quantity     = 1;
            $variation    = array( $variation_attribute  => $variation_attribute_value );

            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );
```

Please note the format you need to pass - `http://example.com/?add-to-cart-manual=44|45|color|green,44|46|color|red` and this is the format -  `product_id1|variation_id1|variation_attribute1|variation_value1,product_id2|variation_id2|variation_attribute2|variation_value2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on product id you can check if product is added in the cart or not.
Here is a code example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_find_product_in_cart' );

function bbloomer_find_product_in_cart() {

    $product_id = 282;

    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

    if ( $in_cart ) {

        $notice = 'Product ID ' . $product_id . ' is in the Cart!';
        wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );

    }

}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: before that i want to add two variable product into cart buy clicking a link